# cursor.forEach is not a function Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Here I am trying to use forEach method to iterate through each document of the cursor and pushing it into the result array but i am getting an error at 
**forEach**

here is my code :

```
    var fetch = function(callback) {
    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/registration');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/questiondb');
    var cursor = user.find();
   cursor.forEach(function (doc,err) {
         if(!err)
             resultArray.push(doc);
         else 
         {
              callback(false);
         }
   },
     function () {
          callback(resultArray);
     });
};
```

error is :
**TypeError: cursor.forEach is not a function**

Comment: what is `user`?  does `user.find` return an array? or at least an object with a forEach method?

Comment: var user = mongoose.model('questions',Schema,'questions'); @JaromandaX

Comment: now, what type of structure does `user.find` return

Comment: var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //  _id    : String,
    question: String,
    A   : String,
    B   : String,
    C   : String,
    D   : String,
    ans : String
});@JaromandaX

Comment: are you sure that's what `cursor` is? I think you need to re-read some mongoose 101 documentation

Comment: You are confusing documentation sources. Mongoose does not have a ["cursor"](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) object like the node native driver of MongoDB does. It can optionally process a "stream", via the [`.stream()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) method which returns a read stream, and a method called [`.cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor) which is a variant on a stream interface, but also still different.

Comment: In most cases though, you simply want to let mongoose do it's default thing, which is to transform the results into an "array". This is a common call as `user.find().exec(function(err,results) { .... })` where `results` is an array of all the items returned by `.find()`. Also see the documentation of [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose's [`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) returns a [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object, not a cursor. Furthermore, if you pass a callback to `find`, you'll get just the behavior you're trying to create with `fetch`, where an array of documents are provided to the callback.

```
var fetch = function(callback) {
    // Don't connect here, connect once during startup
    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/questiondb');

    user.find((err, resultArray) => {
        if (!err) {
            callback(resultArray);
        }
        else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert in array

```
User.find(function (err,userx){
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        //add this code sentence
        var user_arr =Object.keys(userx).map(
            function(key){
                return userx[key];
            }
        );

        //now, use forEach sentence
        user_arr.forEach(function(us){
            console.log(us.name);
        })

    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Because the cursor is **not an array**.forEach function must be used on an array.

Comment: There are many other interfaces besides `Array` that implement a `forEach` method.